# AWS API Gateway - log bad requests?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, logging, lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have logging setup for my api (API Gateway and Lambda).  Where does API Gateway log Apache type HTTPS connection logs?  I would like to see what is hitting the end point that does not map to my API.  For example, my api is domain.com/api/v1/resource, how do I log if a client is trying to hit domain.com/api/v1/some_invalid_resource?  Also API Gateway prevents API abuse (see https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/), how would I know if my API is being attacked if I don't have connect level logs?

Comment: I'm not sure it's known whether API Gateway actually charges for fundamentally invalid requests.

Comment: That is a good question as well, one that we aren't currently concerned about.  We assume we are not charged, otherwise, there would be a metric / logs, which so far, no one is showing where to see them in any forums or searches.  I'll post on AWS forums as well.

Comment: Wow, that conment did not say at all what I intended: I'm not sure whether API Gateway captures logs for fundamentally invalid requests that do not lead it to a valid resource.  Whether there is a charge for those requests was an afterthought.  I went to google it and came back and butchered the comment pretty thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks - where does it log those invalid requests?  No blogs on topic, nothing in AWS Cloudwatch.  Normal access to our API is coming in fine in CloudWatch.  If I curl to the right domain, but invalid API, for example, nothing is logged.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure logging for API Gateway make sure you setup role for writing logs to permit to write it to cloudwatch.

You can see them under cloudwatch like the stream as below,

API-Gateway-Execution-Logs_(APIID)/{stage}

Comment: No, I have that all setup just fine, and logs come in, if my lambda functions match.  What I want is access logs, like Apache or Tomcat has letting me know what kind of traffic is hitting my endpoint so I can manage client bugs, DOS, etc.  I get no logs if a client hits the end point improperly and it doesn't map to a valid API, even if the API gateway domain is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is the official answer from AWS:

Unfortunately, API Gateway doesn't provide access logs for the customer. I will create a feature request on API Gateway side, and API Gateway will consider prioritizing this request, but I cannot provide the ETA for this. As the workaround, you can create a proxy resource with a mock integration at the same level as your other resources, and you will be able to see the logs of the requests that are hitting the wrong resources.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=805138&#805138

Answer (score 0):

You can now Enable Access Logging on a stage of your API Gateway. (See bottom of page here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-logging.html) In my tests so far, it logs correct IP Address, requestTime, and resource path only for valid requests. It logs the attempted access for invalid requests, but does not get IP, requestTime (which you can get from the log entry time anyway), nor attempted path.

I want to enable this to see if someone is trying to probe my API for an attack vector, so so far it isn't incredibly helpful.